# Samsung 32GB microSD card is not detected by Windows

Tags: windows-7, formatting, micro-sd-card

I have an issue with my Samsung microSD card. I formatted this card on Windows. Now Windows doesn't recognize it (0GB free, 0GB used). I think data was deleted, because when I plug it in on Linux the operating system recognizes the 32GB card.

What should I do?

Comment: What filesystem does Linux see?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your SD card partionning is totally screwed.

For instance, this can happen when you directly write an ISO image on a SD card or USB key.

From Linux, use `fdisk`, `parted` or another partitioning tool to set it right:

- remove all the remaining partitions
- create a new one using all the space

Then from Windows, you will be able to format it properly to FAT32 or another filesystem.

Using `fdisk` and assuming you SD card is seen as `/dev/sda`:

`# fdisk /dev/sda`

`Command (m for help):` **p**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 64.4 GB, 64424509440 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7832 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        7832   62806117+   Ob  W95 FAT32
```

`Command (m for help):` **d**

`Partition number (1-4):` **1**

`Command (m for help):` **n**

```
Command action
   e   extended
   p   primary partition (1-4)
```

**p**

`Partition number (1-4):` **1**

...

Comment: As for a non-Linux solution: If I remember correctly, the Disk Management Snap-in refuses to partition SD cards. `diskpart` should be more cooperative. Unfortunately, I cannot verify this now.